# how do i define a function to return False if all items in a list are different and True if not

Tags: python, for-loop

I have tried to make a function that check distinctness of list items, Returning false if there aren't multiple occurrences of the same element.

```
def AllDifferent(s):
    for i in s:
        for i2 in s:
            if i2 == i:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lazy version: `return not (len(set(s)) == len(s))`

Comment: Are the things in the list hashable?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with a `set`.  A `set` is a collection that only keeps one copy of any object.  So `set([1,1,1,1,1,1])` is the same as `set([1])`. So let's just check if the `set` is the same length (size) as the `list`

```
def allDifferent(in_list):
    return len(set(in_list)) == len(in_list)
```

Note that mutable data types in Python are not hashable, and can't go in `set`s. For them we need a more detailed solution.

```
def allDifferent(in_list):
     my_list = in_list[:]
     while my_list:
         x = my_list.pop()
         if x in my_list:
             return False
     return True
```

Comment: `in` is a keyword: You can't use it as a variable.

Comment: @TemporalWolf derp, of course I can't.  That's what i get for trying to be clever. Thanks

Comment: for an earlier question I wrote `sum = *whatever*`, then was trying to `sum(*something else*)` and getting `float is not callable` and it was driving me nuts until I realized I derp'd :)

Answer (score 4):

Your else clause causes the function to end immediately after the first comparison, regardless of whether it is true or false.

Instead, move the "return True" statement outside the loops entirely.  If the loops finish without returning False then it can return True.

Answer (score 1):

[`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) in python stores the unique values. You may check the length of your list and the length of the set of that list. If they are same, all items are unique and if not, then there is duplicate value present. For example:

```
>>> unique_list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # unique values
>>> not len(unique_list) == len(set(unique_list)) # not since you need inverse
False

>>> non_unique_list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1] # non unique values
>>> not len(non_unique_list) == len(set(non_unique_list))
True
```

*Note:* `set()` can be used only with the objects of *immutable* type.

Comment: how is that different from the earlier answer?

Comment: @tinySandy We posted it almost at the same time, with difference of just seconds. I am further updating the answer to make it different

Comment: yeah, he was first though, so i would remove answer since it is the same solution posted later, but it's up to you

Comment: @tinySandy I disagree - this answer shows a working example which is a valuable addition.

Comment: @TemporalWolf and which one is that?

Comment: If anything, I think the minor differences that come out of individual coding styles can be very helpful to people just starting out.

Comment: @anonymous I think your description of `set` vs `frozenset` is incorrect. It is the `set` object itself that is mutable vs immutable. It still only works on immutable objects.

Comment: OP is asking for a list though in his question, so the note is kinda useless in my opinion

Comment: @TemporalWolf I think I didn't got what you mentioned about set vs frozen. I would be glad to know :) Any example or link will be useful

Comment: @anonymous from your link: "A set object is an unordered collection of immutable values." "The set type is mutable" "The frozenset type is immutable and hashable" Sets don't work on mutable objects. the set/frozenset changes whether the set is mutable/immutable, not what type of objects they can store

Comment: Got it. It is not needed here

Answer (score 0):

### You're using Python!

Use Python's special ways to do things! Python has [`list`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) and [`set`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). Set is basically an unordered list, where there are no more than 1 occurrence of the same element.

You can say that casting the `list` to a `set` will eliminate duplicates. So, if we want to check that all elements are distinct (occur only once), we'll have to check that casting the `list` to `set` does not remove any elements. That can be achieved by the `len` function. Let's see how it works:

```
def isDistinct(arr):
    return True if len(set(arr)) == len(arr) else False
```

We return `True` if the list and the distinct list's (set) lengths are equal. Otherwise, we return false.

Of course, `len(set(arr)) == len(arr)` is a boolean expression, so you can omit the `if` clause:

```
def isDistinct(arr):
    return len(set(arr)) == len(arr)
```

Comment: `isDicsinct`  did you mean distinct?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I spotted my mistake before you did ;-) Already fixed